# how to calculate the image scalesize of a watermark image

Tags: itext

I have a piece of code to put an image watermark into an existing pdf. I am looking for a way to calculate the scale percentage of the watermark image

```
 public void MixFiles(String wmrk, String src, String dest)
    {
        string watermarkedFile = dest;

        PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(src);
        PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, new FileStream(dest, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None));
        iTextSharp.text.Image img = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(wmrk);
        PdfContentByte waterMark;
        for (int pageIndex = 1; pageIndex <= pdfReader.NumberOfPages; pageIndex++)
        {
            waterMark = pdfStamper.GetOverContent(pageIndex);
            // the scale percent is found by trial and error how can I calculate it??
            img.ScalePercent(24f);

            img.SetAbsolutePosition(0f, 0f);

            waterMark.AddImage(img);
        }
        pdfStamper.FormFlattening = true;
        pdfStamper.Close();           
    }
```

My code works so far but what happens with other watermark image. What does the scale proportion depend on? The watermark image is a png with a size of 210x297mm the source pdf to bestamped has also pages with 210x297mm both have a resolution of 300 dpi.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that itext uses internaly a 72 dpi resolution. The original resolution of the watermark png is 300 dpi. So 72/300 results with 0.24.
I tried with a 400 dpi watermark and get the expected result with 72/400= 0.18.
For unknown watermark resolution I now use

```
System.Drawing.Image newImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(wmrk);
var reso=newImage.HorizontalResolution;
float scalepercent = (72/reso)*100;  
img.ScalePercent(scalepercent);
```